# Saving a copy of Linked Excel Data in an Access table

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have an excel spreadsheet Linked to my Access database. I am using the Linked Table in Access in a Form that creates a Report.

When new data is added to the Excel file, I run the report.
Now, at the same time I run the report, I want to copy each new record into a local Access table.

Is there a function or Event in a Report that can do that?

Comment: Do you really want a full copy of the Linked Table?  In that case, have you tried simply choosing "Convert to local table" on the object?  Right-click the linked table in the list of all tables in All Access Objects and it is an option.

Comment: Do you want to eliminate the Excel as an input interface? Then do what @MikeM suggested

Comment: I'm using Excel to do calculations for the user then all the sums are linked into Access to be stored and formatted into a report.

Comment: @June7 --- good point.....  that convenient option does remove the Linked Table, so that's important to be aware of.  If you want both, you might prefer to just Import again and choose to create a local table.

Comment: @doigr --  It sounds like maybe we're not clear about what you want.  Do you have a Linked Table today for your Excel?  Does that same Excel file get changed sometimes?

Comment: How difficult are these calculations? Can't just do them in Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple hours of trying things I figured it out! I ran a query on the table and then used the Append option to put it into a new table, then I just run the query in the macro before making the report.

Comment: good :)  Maybe you can make a more detailed example, with some pictures of each step, so other's can learn from it in the future

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import the data rather than link them, use

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, ...
```

to do so.